# python как разобраться с асинхронностью (ошибка: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread')

Tags: python, асинхронность, asyncio, event-loop

```
# Класс, который я далее импортирую и вызову асинхронный метод этого класса для получения результата
class Async_Meta_Trader():
    "Класс для работы с торговым терминалом и данными: Класс Meta_Trader login и password, server\
    данные эти берем в последующем из файла конфигурации json"
    def __init__(self, login_user: int, password_user: str, server_user: str):
        self.login = login_user
        self.password = password_user
        self.server = server_user

    async def account_info(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        "Метод для получения информации об торговом счете из терминала"
        if not mt5.initialize(login=self.login, password=self.password, server=self.server):
            logger.warning(f"initialize() failed connecting to account_trader MetaTrader5, error code = {mt5.last_error()}")
        else:
            print('Подключение к торговому счету успешно')
            account_info_dict = mt5.account_info()._asdict()
            df = pd.DataFrame(account_info_dict.items(), columns=['Key', 'Value'])  # конвертация 
            return df
```

```
import aiocron   # для выполнения задач по расписанию
import asyncio
from My_Class_functions import Meta_Trader   # импортировал класс в ко-м есть асин.метод account_info


Terminal = Meta_Trader(login_user=012313, password_user="test", server_user="test")
temp_df = asyncio.run(Terminal.account_info())    # получаю результат из асинх. метода, ко-й в далее вызовет ошибку в ниже следующей асин.функции

@aiocron.crontab(('*/1 * * * *'))   # декоратор для вызов асин. функции каждую минуту 
async def get_test():            # ??? здесь вызывает ошибку There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'                 # 
    print("run")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

** Как корретно работать с асинхронными методами :(

Comment: Может поможет < https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/1146>

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `asyncio.get_event_loop()` на `asyncio.new_event_loop()`. Да и метод `account_info` вполне может быть синхронным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По вопросу могу предположить, что вы не сильно разбираетесь в асинхронном коде, так что вот пример:

```
import asyncio


class Test:
    def __init__(self, num: int):
        self.some_num = num

    async def some_async_method(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Важно: Асинхронный под не выполняется параллельно. Он выполняется тогда, когда какая-либо функция чего-то ждёт (в данном случае asyncio.sleep(1)) и в этот момент передает управление на другую
        print(f"some_async_method num = {self.some_num}")


async def update_data(instance: Test):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        instance.some_num += 1


async def print_data(instance: Test):
    while True:
        await instance.some_async_method()


async def main():
    instance = Test(10)
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(print_data(instance)), asyncio.create_task(update_data(instance))]  # Создание задач для выполнения в event loop
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)  # Можно просто ожидать конца выполнения функций (в этом случае вечность)
    # await asyncio.sleep(100)  Или настроить время, которое будет работать скрипт. Если убрать sleep, то python запустит 2 таска и продолжит выполнять код ниже, а так как его нету - просто выйдет из приложения
    # Или вообще ничего не ждать и выполнять код дальше


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

А в вашем коде попробуйте заменить `asyncio.get_event_loop()` на `asyncio.new_event_loop()`.
Также можете посмотреть [это](https://youtu.be/t5Bo1Je9EmE) видео по теме.

Comment: О Спасибо Вам ) сегодня буду копаться изучать ...